# Proprietary Nvidia drivers cause screen tearing in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, tearing

No matter what drivers and or settings I use I still get bad screen tearing when using nvida proprietary drivers and the nouveau drivers seem to be disabling my graphics card altogether and use my intel integrated graphics instead.

Info about my hardware in case it helps: 
It's an ASUS ROG GL551JW-DS74 15.6 Inch laptop

128gb SSD boot drive w/ 2x 1tb HDDs for storage
 Gpu - Nvidia geforce GTX 960m
 Cpu - intel i7 quad core w/ integrated graphics

Comment: Which version of drivers are you using? For best results install latest drivers via https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa make sure you remove do a sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia* before installing the new drivers.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/649961/my-new-nvidia-card-has-screen-tearing-in-games Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

First follow the previous post for re-installing your drivers, then try the below.

**Duplicate:**

Two steps that solved the problem for me on my gtx 960 on Kubuntu 14.04

1st try adding this to your xorg.conf file @ /etc/X11/

`Section "Screen"`

`Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceFullComposition = On}"`

If that works only sometimes or distorts clarity on internet or game video then add this and it should make a big difference and hopefully permanent fix.

`Section "Screen"`

`Option         "TripleBuffer" "1"`

---

You can check out my research [here-askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/701787/260142).