# Screen tearing when scrolling and in games

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, screen

I've been getting screen tearing that is only present in Ubuntu (MATE 16.04).

Often when scrolling on pages, I get a horizontal line that tears through, and the same goes for games, particularly Minecraft (whenever I look around there is a horizontal tear)

It is extremely frustrating because the issue is not present in Windows.

I am using an i5-3570k with a NVIDIA GTX 670. Currently using the NVIDIA 361.42 proprietary drivers available through the driver options.

I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics) by putting a configuration file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d as well as [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/652268/550435) to no avail.

Comment: Try opening "MATE Tweak" from the preferences menu. What is selected as your compositor? Try the other options one-by-one to see what works best

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late here, but since you are using a NVIDIA graphics card the problem can be solved by editing `nvidia-settings` (make sure `nvidia-settings` is installed):

- Open `nvidia-settings` (as root, via `sudo`).
- Go to *XServer Display Configuration*.
- Click on *Advanced*.
- Enable *Force full composition pipeline* or *Force composition pipeline* (depends on what feels best for you). If you can't see the checkbox for these options, you have to click "Advanced" in the lower-right of the window:
  [screenshot showing "Advanced" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsisO.png)
- Click *Apply* and check if the tearing is gone. Remember you have to do above step for **each** monitor.
- Make sure to hit *Save to x configuration file*. If you don't have write permission for `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` then save to your home directory and afterwards do:

  `sudo cp /home/<username>/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- Restart your PC after following these steps.

This solves almost all screen-tearing related problems with proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: There is no ' force full composition pipeline'  or any other similar option in the UI.

Comment: I do the 'force full composition pipeline' on Nvidea Settings app, but not change nothing.

Comment: After switching GPUs, I also encountered tearing. This answer immediately helped.